# Websites for 'Normalizing' CSS?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I recently found the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) site for easily generating CSS gradients across all browser platforms.  It's perfect for what I was looking for.  However, I've also encountered other aspects of CSS that require multiple declarations to be cross-browser compatible (i.e. anything like -webkit-*).  It's a pain in the butt to develop using multiple browser types.  I prefer to develop in Firefox with Firebug for initial testing, and then obviously do cross-browser testing as QA.

My question is, does anyone know of sites that will let me plugin my existing CSS (which may be Firefox or Safari or whatever-specific) and have it 'normalize' it with the appropriate browser-specific declarations for other browsers?  Say, for example, I have something like this in my CSS:

```
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
```

I'd like to be able to plugin a CSS file that has those declarations all over the place, and have the site also add things like...

```
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
```

(and whatever the equivalent is on other browsers)

Anyone know of a tool or site that will accomplish this?  It obviously doesn't eliminate the need to do extensive cross-browser testing before shipping, but I would imagine it would reduce development time significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prefixr](http://prefixr.com) is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can try this super-useful javascript plugin by Lea Verou: [Prefix Free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)

> -prefix-free lets you use only unprefixed CSS properties everywhere. It works behind the scenes, adding the current browser’s prefix to any
>   CSS code, only when it’s needed.

It probably needs an update, because sometimes radial gradients won't display without vendor prefixes. But for most common properties, like `border-radius`, `box-sizing`, `box-shadow` etc. is great.

Comment: PrefixFree is the greatest thing since sliced bread. Just use non-prefixed properties in your stylesheet, add in the plugin, and it'll dynamically add a prefix depending on the browser (if it needs a prefix at all). I just include this plugin in all my projects by default now.

Comment: Me too @daGUY, but still we need to test, because it fails with some latest features, like `background-origin` and radial gradients

Comment: Oh yeah, of course you still need to test, but it still helps tremendously vs. manually adding all the prefixes yourself and making sure the values all match between them...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for http://prefixmycss.com/